# Web View is not working in iOS5

Tags: ipad, ios5

I am **very** new to iPad and was trying "Loading a web page using the Web View" - opening the google page!

I followed all the steps given in the box/tutorial but I am not able to view the page.
Step 1 : Added web view in the view window
Step 2 : decalre outlet for web view by adding following code

```
@interface WebiPadViewController : UIViewController {
   IBOutlet UIWebView *webDisplayiPad;
 }
 @property(nonatomic,retain) UIWebView *webDisplayiPad;
```

Step 3 : Connect webview outlet to Web view using file manager
Step 4 : Create URl and request object using followng code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

 //Create a URL object.
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
  [webDisplayiPad loadRequest:requestObj];

 [super viewDidLoad];
 }
```

Step 5 : Save and run the app to see google page.

But the Simulator shows only a white background!

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying it is possible you simply haven't setup your ViewController class and View outlet property properly, as sergio describes, since that can also lead to a blank white background.

But I'm going to assume that it is your webDisplayiPad property that is not connected. I think this most likely since your "Step 3 : Connect webview outlet to Web view using file manager" seems a sketchy description at best.

To check your connection go to your WebiPadViewController.xib and right-click (cntrl-click) on the File's Owner icon. Under outlets there should be your webDisplayiPad listed with a circle to the right of it. If the circle is empty, and I suspect it is, drag from the circle to the UIWebView. The UIWebView will do a little flash to confirm. And your done.

Also the modern way of connecting IBOutlets is to put that keyword in the property definition and forget the ivar completely. For example:

```
@interface WebiPadViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webDisplayiPad;
```

and in the .m file to do this:

```
@implementation WebiPadViewController
@synthesize webDisplayiPad = _webDisplayiPad;
```

The synthesize will create the backing variable for you and the _ character will help you keep them straight.

If you were to change to this way your loadRequest call would look like one of the following two:

```
[_webDisplayiPad loadRequest:requestObj]; // Calls through ivar
[self.webDisplayiPad loadRequest:requestObj]; // Calls through accessor method
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget in you implementation:

```
@synthesize webDisplayiPad = _webDisplayiPad;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you got some problems with your Nib/Xib connections.

Please, check the following:

1. your nib's file's owner class is set to be `WebiPadViewController`;
2. your controller's `view` outlet is connected to the web view.

Comment: Assert may help - NSAssert( webDisplayiPad, @"did i hook up the outlet?");

Answer (score 0):

**Set delegate.**
web page loads only when u set the delegate.

other wise it will be an empty page

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to load HTML into a UIWebView,

Comment: `[webDisplayiPad loadRequest:requestObj]` is perfectly ok to get the web view loaded with some html; the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: @Stuti. In fact loadRequest is used in the link you posted.